# Android deep link from sms. Open in new task

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, deep-linking

So i have looked at similar questions but not found the solution for my own. I have a link in a sms message that launches my application. The issue is that when the application launches it opens in the current task. I need to launch the app in a new task, as though the user has clicked the icon to start it. The solutions ive seen to launching the app in a new task have always been in code launching one activity from another, however my use case is different since im linking from a sms message.

The application is xamarin.android, you can see the intent below.

```
[Activity(NoHistory = true, Theme = "@style/AppTheme.Login", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask)]
[IntentFilter(
    new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable},
    DataScheme = "https", DataHost = "mywebsite.co.uk", DataPathPrefix = "/login", AutoVerify = true)]
```

So the app does open but it opens in the message application, not in a new task like required. The link sent in the message is **https://mywebsite.co.uk/login**

I beleive the dificulty with this is because im launching the app from an sms message so its hard to state that i want it to open in a new task. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You've specified `launchMode="singleTask"` and that should be enough. How do you know if it launched into the messaging task?

Comment: Im not sure what the correct term is but when you the square button and it shows the active applications, i see my application running but the header is messages, where as i would expect to see my app and the message app running separately

Comment: To be sure, please launch your app from SMS and then do `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` and post the output.